# static network setup still using DHCP

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, linux-networking, static-ip

I'm configuring an Ubuntu 14.04LTS server on our internal network.  Everything works and runs as expected.  Its assigned a static IP, here's /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.250
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        dns-nameservers 192.168.10.1
        gateway 192.168.10.1
```

But when our router restarts and/or network goes down the server pulls a DHCP address and ignores the static IP.  I tried removing "auto eth0" but it didn't change the situation.

If I reboot the server then the static IP always comes back.  How can I force it to always use the static IP?

EDIT with answers to questions:

- Not a virtual machine
- dhclient is running (twice?)
- No VPNs on this box
- Nothing in the log about eth0 but wlan0 seems to be reconnecting to an access point on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: Is this computer a VM?   Do you the dhcp client running in your process table?  Do you have any unusual VPNs on this box?  Does anything show up in your system logs the the IP changes?

Comment: Check to make sure network manger is at least disabled if not uninstalled.

Comment: @Zoredache, looks like dhclient is running, I've edited the question with answers to your questions

Comment: @BillThor network manager was running, I shut it off.  We'll see what happens tonight

Comment: Well the server still defaulted to DHCP.  The funny thing though, when I log in it says the IP is 192.168.10.250 (what its supposed to be) but its answering on a DHCP assigned address elsewhere instead.  I'm currently uninstalling (rather than just disabling) network manager to make sure that's not causing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Sadler's answer will work, but it's quite heavy handed. Here is how you can disable an interface from being managed by Network Manager without uninstalling it.

```
# network manager cli
$ sudo nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eth1    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

You can see `eth1` is managed by network manager.

In Ubuntu/debian flavors edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[ifupdown]
managed=false
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth1  # <--- Add this line
```

Then restart the service.

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Verify.

```
$ sudo nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
eth1    ethernet  unmanaged  --           # <--- it's now unmanaged.
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had installed a desktop on the server which had included the network manager and this was running the dhclient at startup. Uninstalling the network manager and rebooting solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
sudo reboot
```